# Arraylist calling by constructor

Tags: java

I created an ArrayList and tried to call the getAverage method on myAnalyzer and specifying myClassroom as the argument (parameter). But it didn't worked out 
it gives the following error,

```
GradeAnalyzer.java:40: error: method getAverage in class GradeAnalyzer cannot be applied to given types;

myAnalyzer.getAverage(myClassroom);
        ^
required: no arguments
found: ArrayList<Integer>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GradeAnalyzer{
    //constructor
    public GradeAnalyzer(){
    }
    //method get average created returns int
    public int getAverage(){
        ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(grades.size() < 1){
            System.out.println("Arraylist is empty");
            return 0;
        }else{
            int sum = 0;      
            for(Integer grade :grades){
                sum = grade + sum;
            }
            int average = sum/grades.size();
            System.out.println(average);
            return average;
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> myClassroom = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myClassroom.add(98);
        myClassroom.add(92);
        myClassroom.add(88);
        myClassroom.add(75);
        myClassroom.add(61);
        myClassroom.add(89);
        myClassroom.add(95);
        System.out.println(myClassroom);
        GradeAnalyzer myAnalyzer = new GradeAnalyzer(); 
        myAnalyzer.getAverage(myClassroom);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `getAverage` method is declared to not take any parameters

Comment: The formatting makes it hard er to read the code, I suggest you use the code formatter in your IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `getAverage()`method doesn't take a parameter. Instead you create a new empty list inside of it.
Change it to

```
public int getAverage(List<Integer> grades){
    if(grades.size() < 1){
    ...
}
```